# Angular Object literal may only specify know properties and ... does not exist in type

Tags: angular

I'm starting out with Angular and running into an error.

> .../mocks.ts(9,4): Type '{"id": number; "name": string; "description": string; "inStock": number; "price": number; "featu...' is not assignable to type 'CarPart[].
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"featured"' does not exist in type 'CarPart'.

My code:

car-part.ts

```
export class CarPart {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    inStock: number;
    price: number;
    featured: boolean;
}
```

mock.ts

```
import { CarPart } from './car-part';

export const CARPARTS: CarPart[] = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super Tires",
    "description": "These tires are the very best",
    "inStock": 5,
    "price": 299.99,
    "featured": false //Line 9
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Reinforced Shocks",
    "description": "Shocks made of kryptonite",
    "inStock": 4,
    "price": 500.50,
    "featured": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Padded Seats",
    "description": "Super soft seats for a smooth ride",
    "inStock": 0,
    "price": 333.33,
    "featured": true
  }];
```

car-parts.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarPart } from './car-part';
import { CARPARTS } from './mock';

@Component({
  selector: 'car-parts',
  templateUrl: './car-parts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-parts.component.css']
})
export class CarPartsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  carParts: CarPart[];

  totalCarParts(){
    let sum = 0;

    for(let carPart of this.carParts){
        sum += carPart.inStock;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carParts = CARPARTS;
  }

}
```

when I remove "featured" from both mock.ts and car-part.ts it is fine, no error. If I add it or any other name or type, it wont work...
Can someone explain this?

Comment: what line does it give you an error on? what ts version do you use?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try this: "export const CARPARTS: Array<CarPart>", and/or "export const CARPARTS: Array<Any>. See if either of them get around the error. I get this may not be ideally what you want, but might give a hint as to what's going on. The intial part of the error, "can not assign etc. etc. to (your array)" is what makes me suspicious. Aside from that go through the agony of checking all your versions, etc (are you using an old CLI, all that).

Comment: @Maximus Line 9 in mock.ts (marked it in the code). And i'm using TS version ~2.2.0

Comment: @TimConsolazio Tried both, but the Array<CarPart> gave the same error. And Array<Any>  gives another error: Cannot find name 'Any'. The weird thing is. without 'featured' it all works. When I try to add another property besides the top 5 (id, name, descr, inStock and price) it errors out...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I restarted the Angular CLI server (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > ng serve).
Compiled without problems...

Evidence that "Have you tried turning it off and on again" is still relevant.
Thanks for the time looking at the problems Tim and Max

Comment: I don't believe it works for me too :| What is wrong with CLI compiler ????? any way thanks man :D