# Type Error in Angular but no error in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm begining with Angular (No AngularJS),
I'm trying to make a service that provides the Images data for a Gallery. I'm using Visual Studio Code and it seems to have no errors, but when Angular CLI compiles returns a Type error:

> ERROR in mock-gallery.ts (4,32): Type '{ id: number; name: string;
>   style: string; animation: string; }[]' is not assignable to type
>   'Image[]'.   Type '{ id: number; name: string; style: string;
>   animation: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Image'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'style' does not exist in type 'Image'.

**mock-gallery.ts**

```
import { Image } from './gallery';

export const GALLERY: Image[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'LM01.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 2, name: 'LM02.jpg', style: 'wide gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp'},
    { id: 3, name: 'LM03.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 4, name: 'LM04.jpg', style: 'gallery-big-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 5, name: 'LM05.jpg', style: 'gallery-big-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 6, name: 'LM06.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 7, name: 'LM07.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 8, name: 'LM08.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 9, name: 'LM09.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 10, name: 'LM10.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 11, name: 'LM04.jpg', style: 'gallery-big-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 12, name: 'LM05.jpg', style: 'gallery-big-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 13, name: 'LM06.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 14, name: 'LM07.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 15, name: 'LM01.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 16, name: 'LM02.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
    { id: 17, name: 'LM03.jpg', style: 'gallery-small-height', animation: 'wow animated fadeInUp' },
];
```

**gallery.ts**

```
export class Image {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  style: string;
  animation?: string;
}
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but note that you do not need a type `class` here, you should use an `interface` (e.g., `export interface Image {...}`): classes are emitted to JavaScript, whereas interfaces are only used by tsc for type-assertion. Classes are really only useful when you want methods or default initializers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676122/angular-object-literal-may-only-specify-know-properties-and-does-not-exist-i 
have you looked at this?

Comment: Thanks @msanford, I will take your suggest to be more practical.